# Find the limit of a sequence $(\frac{z^n}{n!})_{n=1}^{\infty}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I have to find the limit of a sequence $(\frac{z^n}{n!})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ where $z$ is a complex number. I think it is zero, because we know that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!}$ is finite. Is this a good explanation?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: How can one show it without refering to that fact? I know that sequences of compelx numbers are convergent if both real and imaginary parts are convergent.

Comment: $$e^x=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{x^r}{r!}$$

Comment: Although, to show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$ is finite, you need to have shown that the terms converge to $0$ (quickly enough). So maybe it is better not to use the exponential series in that argument.

Comment: so which argument can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation isn't good because to prove that series converges firstly you have to prove that it's terms tend to zero at least.

There is such $N > 0$ that $2|z| < N$. Then for $n > N$ we have:

$$
\Big|\frac{z^n}{n!}\Big| \leq \frac{|z|^n}{n!} = \frac{|z|^N}{N!} \cdot \frac{|z|^{n-N}}{(N + 1) \cdots n} \leq Const \cdot \frac{1}{2^{n-N}}
$$

Which is tending to zero as long as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $N$ is fixed.

Comment: If you *know* that the series converges, you have shown that its terms tend to zero, but these statements are not equivalent. So proving that the series converges does imply that the terms tend to zero and is not a wrong way of proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

When you are given a Taylor series, you can compute its radius of convergence by considering the values of $z$ where the following goes to zero as $n \to \infty$: 
$$
\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| = \frac{|z|^{n+1}/(n+1)!}{|z|^n/n!} = \frac {|z|}{n+1}.
$$
Since this goes to zero for any value of $z$, the series is convergent for any value of $z$, thus your sequence goes to zero for any $z$. You don't need to mention $e^z$ for this, you just say "I consider this series and look at its radius of convergence, which turns out to be infinite, so the series converges for all $z$".

Hope that helps,